# How to search Ruby/Rails' syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

As a beginner, I always have problems about some method when coding. For example, when I'm writing a import csv feature, I don't know whether a `new` could take a block as a variable, and what the `CSV.foreach` iterates through.

```
def self.import(file, date)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, header: true) do |row|
    point = Point.find_or_create_by_name(row["name"])
    point.observations.new do |observation|
      observation.value =  row["value"]
      observation.record_date = date
    end
  end
end
```

For most developers, these are easy questions, but for beginners like me, these are real-life problems that we really struggle about.

How do we search for Ruby's syntax?

Comment: Looks at the docs? Also, this isn't a question of syntax, but usage. In addition to ruby-doc.org, there's also apidock, Dash and its clones, ri, pry-doc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/)?

- [`CSV.foreach(path, options = Hash.new, &block)`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach)